# Latest model data is not reflected in a grid view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

There are two pages where we are showing "notes" collection, on both the views - We are using the same collection object and model objects for displaying notes. If I am updating or modifying the notes on one page on the other page the notes collection is not fetching the latest data.

How to fetch and sync the data in order to refresh the grid view and show the latest collection objects?

```
define([
   'utilsjscommon/views/BaseView',
   'utilsjscommon/views/ModalView',
   'utilsjscommon/views/grid/GridView',
   'collections/AccountNoteCollection',
   'models/AccountNoteModel',
   'views/insured/NoteModalView',
   'text!templates/insured/InsuredNoteTemplate.html'
], function (BaseView, ModalView, GridView, AccountNoteCollection, 
AccountNoteModel, NoteModalView, Template) {

var view = BaseView.extend({
template: _.template(Template),

events: {
  'click button.new-note': 'newNote',
  'click button.delete-note': 'deleteNote',
  'click button.edit-note': 'editNote'
},

init: function () {
  this.noteGrid = new GridView({
    collectionClass: AccountNoteCollection,
    gridStyle: 'condensed',
    perPage: 8,
    defaultSort: ['enteredon|desc'],
    columns: {
      note: {
        href: true
      },
      enteredby: { header: 'entered by' },
      enteredon: {
        header: 'entered on',
        type: 'date'
      }
    },
    paginationStyle: 'small',
    maxPageControl: 3,
    multiSelect: false
  });
    this.model.bind('reset', this.render, this);
  this.subviews.push(this.noteGrid);
},

render: function () {
  this.$el.html(this.template());

  this.listenTo(this.noteGrid, 'resetControls', this.resetNoteControls);
  this.$('#ud_noteGrid').html(this.noteGrid.render().el);
    return this;
},

refresh: function () {
  this.getNotes();

},


getNotes: function () {
    this.noteGrid.fetch({
        insuredid: this.model.get('insuredid')
    });
},
```

Comment: What do you mean by two pages? Two browser windows/tabs? Two backbone views in same window? Your question is not clear

Comment: Sorry for that On clicking a hyperlink of the first page it will redirect to the 2nd page under the same window tab

Comment: Are you making sure this hyperlink is not enabled while data is sent to the server and you receive success response?

Comment: Hyperlink will be always enabled - the View is loaded initially fetching the data from the server - and from the next time it is rendering  the existing view

Comment: You say "If I am updating or modifying the notes" - what if user clicks the link while this haven't been done successfully on server? Are you sure the data is getting updated in the server? If yes, have you checked what data is being retrieved from server on the second page? If it's not the updated data then it's a serverside problem. If data is not being updated on server it has nothing to do with syncing pages, you just need to fix it

Comment: I think I misunderstood, If you're passing around the existing data from first view to second view without updating the data on server  why do you do `this.noteGrid.fetch` ..? This will reset your data from server

Comment: I am pretty sure  data is getting updated in the server , because once i add the data on the first page - click on hyperlink - which redirects to 2nd page - its not showing the latest data , but if i refresh the page the latest data is populating , As you said if the data is not getting upated in server - I would never get the data back on refresh ,

Comment: refresh: function () {
      this.getNotes();

    },

      
    getNotes: function () {

        /*alert(this.model.get('insuredid'));

        alert(new AccountNoteCollection(this.model.get('insuredid')));*/

        this.noteGrid.fetch({
            //collection: new AccountNoteCollection(this.model.get('insuredid')),
            insuredid: this.model.get('insuredid')
        });

Comment: Only in the refresh Function We are triggering the GetNotes () .

Comment: Please help me with some links where i can check - how to get the latest modified collection data in a grid ( For Backbone.JS)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some sample code of how you're initializing second view. Code blocks are not readable in comments

Comment: I have edited the post with correct question now

Comment: There is no code that creates a new view and passes data to it on click of hyperlink in the shared code?

Comment: You need to include a [mcve] in the question itself. This is not a debugging service.